# Does it matter which character I select?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

When starting the first episode you must select one of six characters.  Does this choice affect any future choices?  Is there any point in replaying the game using a different character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it only effects is:

- What you look like in the gameplay.
- If people call you a he or she, or act like one.

You can't choose your Jesse skin once you start doing the story.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the female Jesse would make others call you 'she', and you will be a female. Lukas would also act different. Petra won't act very reliant as to the male Jesse.